# How to write low quality video without anti-aliasing?

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, codec, scikits

I have `numpy` array of `grayscale` pictures with shape (30,30).
The problem is that, when i write it with

`cv2.VideoWriter(name + '.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'FFV1'), fps=24, (30, 30), False)`

or

`skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter("test.avi", outputdict={'-vcodec': 'libx264', '-crf': '0','-preset':'veryslow'})`

My squence of images becomes from that.

[image: raw picture with plt.imshow()]

to that:

[image: picture from avi video file opened with vlc with h264 codec]

So I want my video without any interpolation.

I know about resizing(for example `cv2.INTER_NEAREST`), but in this case it is not an option.

How to write raw images in video fromat?
Does `vlc` player affects on video reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ffv1 lossless intraframe codec with ffmpeg.
For example

```
cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"FFV1")
```

Then changed video output module in vlc to Windows gdi, like it was written [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1115154/vlc-avoid-interpolation-between-pixel-when-resizing-the-window-playing-a-low-r)